# What are the C++ improvements in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I'm upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and [Description of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432) mentions only a few minor bug fixes and added code generation for AVX2 instruction set. Was there any progress made in C++11/C++14 language and library conformance?

Comment: No, they don't upgrade the compiler in updates. You'll have to wait for the next version of VS. Anyway, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Praetorian Why is it off-topic? _What topics can I ask about here?_ section says that _software tools commonly used by programmers_ is a proper topic.

Comment: I suppose I did jump the gun a bit with that close vote, I apologize for that. Anyway, I answered your question too, you won't find anything other than bug fixes, if any, to the C++ compiler, in Update2. Even with those, I believe they only fix what they deem to be critical bugs.

Comment: There are only bugfixes for the C++ compiler in this update, nothing new.

Comment: @MariusBancila Code generation for AVX2 was added, so you can't say there is nothing new.

Comment: @PaulJurczak how is that related to "C++11/C++14 language and library conformance"?

Comment: @MariusBancila Not at all, but it is related to the title question: `C++ improvements`.

Answer (score 3):

Herb Sutter said at Going Native 2013 and again Build 2014 that there will be an out of band update for VC++ to C++14 when it is ratified.